# How to show object outlines in editor viewport regardless of selection?

Tags: 3d-view

I am positioning flat planes into my scene like this.

[image]

It's much easier for me to work in top-down view on the left, however I can't get a very good idea of the layout without the orange outlines. I have to constantly select all to get a good glimpse, and deselect if I want to make more modifications to individual planes.

Is there a way to enable the outlines regardless of selections?

I'm aware I can use modifiers to thicken my planes, or even put them at a slight angle so they become visible in top-down view, but I'd rather a pure editor tooling solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You could turn Wireframe on: https://i.imgur.com/Xe09gQ3.png Would that be enough? You can right click and assign a shortcut to it to toggle on and off, that's what I usually do.

Comment: If you set your left 3D viewport to wireframe mode you'll be able to see them, but they'll be very thin

Comment: Cheers guys, I don't know why I didn't think of wireframe for this use case!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by commentators, wireframe mode works well for this purpose!

Z > Wireframe

[image]